# Cell Remains Blank When Copying to Other Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet, copying

I'm copying data from Worksheet1 & Worksheet2 into Worksheet3.

The code goes through the desired range in Worksheet 1, finds an X and copies the value of the column 9 rows to the right of the X to Worksheet3. Then it does the same on Worksheet2.

```vb
Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
Dim WrkShtCol As Sheets
Dim cl As range
Dim rw As range

Sub CopyFromSheetsToOtherSheet()

Set WrkShtCol = Worksheets(Array("Worksheet1", "Worksheet"))

For Each WrkSht In WrkShtCol

    For Each rw In WrkSht.range(Antwortrange).Rows   'Reihen durchlaufen innerhalb der Antwortrange
        For Each cl In rw.Cells
            If LCase(cl.Value) = "x" Then
                cl.Offset(0, 9).Copy Sheets("Worksheet3").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)       'Jede Zelle mit Value "x" 9 Spalten nach rechts auswählen (Handlungsempfehlung), weitergeben
            End If
        Next cl
    Next rw
```

The code starts copying into Worksheet3 starting at Cell A2, then A3, A4 and so on.
I want it to start at A1. Why doesn't it copy to A1 as the first step?

I'm later using functions to find blanks and therefore I can't have a blank in Cell A1.

Comment: `Sheets("Worksheet3").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ` - the `Offset(1)` means that if `A1` is the first cell, `A2` will be the cell copied to.

Comment: Hm Ok but the thing is I need the Offset(1) so that after each row gets filled, the next one row after gets filled and so on. How can I keep this while still starting at Cell A1?

Comment: You can test if the result of `End(xlUp).Row` = 1.

Comment: Ok yes I see but where do I test it and what to I do if it is/isn't 1? If it is 1 then delete first cell shifting the below cells up so I can delete the empty cell A1 and make everything go one row up? Im not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this but first thing to that came to mind is to just add some conditional checks on your last row calculation (`lr`)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet3")

'For Each cl...

    lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    If lr = 2 And ws.Range("A1") = "" Then lr = 1
    cl.Offset(0, 9).Copy ws.Range("A" & lr)

'Next cl...
```

---

When using `Offset(1)` in this scenario you will end up with `lr = 2` two times. First when the column is blank and again when only `A1` is used. To resolve you can just add a conditional statement when `lr = 2` to determine which range to go with

Comment: This is it, thank you so much. Blank is gone and I can use lr to find the last row every time. Big thanks, honestly! One little thing: Would you have any idea how to after Worksheet1 got pasted, make Worksheet 2 go into the next Column? I think I would have to replace the "A" in your first line with a String that Says B on the next and so on (cycle throuhg alphabet) but this doesnt seem ideal. Any way to do this with numbers? As Columns are Letters it seems hard for me because with rows u can just do +1 (numbers)... Thank you so much though, orignal problem solved!

Comment: You can iterate columns by index with `Cells( Row #, Column #)` or by using `Offset ( Rows, Columns)`

Comment: I would actually modify this to isolate the `If lr = 2` statement. No need to test `ws.Range("A1") = ''` when `lr <> 2`. Maybe a little more efficient. Also, note shorter solutions are not always the best. I like bigbens solution more tbh

Answer (score 2):

```
Sheets("Worksheet3").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

If the first blank cell is `A1`, then due to the `Offset(1)`, `A1` will always be skipped.

Perhaps use a helper function like this:

```
Private Function GetNextAvailableCell( _
   ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
   ByVal colNumber As Long _
) As Range

   With ws
      Dim tempRng As Range
      Set tempRng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colNumber).End(xlUp)
   End With

   If Not IsEmpty(tempRng) Then
      Set tempRng = tempRng.Offset(1)
   End If

   Set GetNextAvailableCell = tempRng
End Function
```

Then use it like this:

```
cl.Offset(0, 9).Copy GetNextAvailableCell(Sheets("Worksheet3"), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, already used urdearboys answer but this is the same approach and would probably work too! See my answer on his comment for follow up question but thanks already, orignal problem solved! :)

Comment: @Leon - for your follow-up question, you can use the helper function above, and then use a variable instead of the `1` when calling it. Then increment that variable by one after `Next cl`. Or use `Cells` instead of `Range` with urdearboy's answer.

Comment: So for urdearboys anwer you mean Range istead of Cell, so 
`lr = ws.range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row` but how would this go to the next column after copying one worksheet? Sorry, am a little confused but I cant thank you enough for taking time to help me :)

Comment: `lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)` - use `Cells`, not `Range`. `Cells` accepts the column index. Instead of the `1`, use a variable.

Comment: I see, Ive done that but the main line that does all the copying  is `cl.Offset(0, 9).Copy Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").range("A" & lr)` and I would have to replace the "A" through the next Column "B" and so on, right? no way to change this to a new variable / Number instead of String "A", "B" and so on for the columns?

Comment: Use `Cells` instead of `Range`.

Comment: I just had the biggest "ahhhhh" moment. Sorry I misunderstood before, this works like a charm <3 Big thanks to Big Boy BigBen u the man